# How to set date.timezone for CodeIgniter to work with php 5.3

Tags: codeigniter, datetime, php

When date.timezone in php.ini is commented out, it gives me:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: main(): It is not safe to
>   rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use
>   the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function.
>   In case you used any of those methods
>   and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled
>   the timezone identifier. We selected
>   'America/Los_Angeles' for '-8.0/no
>   DST' instead
>
> Filename: controllers/helloworld.php
>
> Line Number: 2

When I have

```
date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```

It gives me this:

> Server error The website encountered
>   an error while retrieving
>   http://localhost/ci/index.php/helloworld.
>   It may be down for maintenance or
>   configured incorrectly. Here are some
>   suggestions: Reload this web page
>   later. HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server
>   Error): An unexpected condition was
>   encountered while the server was
>   attempting to fulfill the request.

I am using php 5.3, CodeIgniter 2.0.0, and Apache 2.2.

Update 1:
I tried loading a test.php without CodeIgniter, where the first 3 lines of test.php is

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date("l j \of F Y h:i:s A");
```

And it works fine, different timezones also works fine too.
So I suspect the problem is from CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you Googled "CodeIgniter PHP 5.3" you would have found this article pretty quickly :)

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/12/CodeIgniter-on-PHP-5.3

To fix this, you only need to edit the main index.php for your CodeIgniter application:

```
if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
   date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
}
```

This modification is something you will probably need to make for any CodeIgniter application running on PHP 5.3 and can easily be modified to your local timezone. There is a full list of supported timezones in the PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: I tried that too. I receive the same server error message as setting date.timezone directly in php.ini

Comment: I still can't find the solution, but thanks for helping! I checked the logs, but I didn't find anything useful (or maybe I am checking the wrong log). However, I found that code igniter does not fully support php5. As a result, I decided to drop code igniter. Anyways, thanks for helping again.

Comment: What are you talking about? CodeIgniter does not support PHP 5? Of course it bloody does - I have used CodeIgniter on PHP 5.3 several times without any problem. You have some sort of error with how your server is set up which you need to deal with, not just blame/drop CI.

Comment: I put it in (environment-specific) config.php directly following the timezone variable, that will also work: `date_default_timezone_set($config['time_reference']);`

Answer (score 21):

Yes, if you cannot directly edit the php.ini file, placing...

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/New_York');
```

...as the first line in CI's index.php works fine.

Reference: [PHP's Available Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 8):

write in your index.php codeigniter...

```
/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| TimeZone 
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| default Time Zone
| 

*/
if ( function_exists( 'date_default_timezone_set' ) )
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
```

Running well in my codeigniter

Answer (score 4):

this is the simple way to do it

```
$timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
//echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

$localtime=date('H:i:s');

$sql="INSERT INTO hits (ip,edate,curtime,page_name) VALUES ('$ip', CURDATE(),'$localtime','$filename') ";
```

Answer (score 3):

date.timezone is intended to go in your php.ini or .htaccess file.

you could do an `ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');` in the first line of your script and get the desired results.

Comment: I am using code igniter, so the first line of my script means the index.php under my CI folder?

Comment: @snowfish, yes... this is the exact same solution i posted :/

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I have made all these changes in index.php as well as php.ini. But still its showing server time. Please help me to solve out this.

Comment: @sushil You should probably contact your host and ask why you are not allowed to override the default timezone within PHP.

Comment: @RobertM. I have contacted with them, and they said they are not responsible for such changes. I have to make these changes from coding part. I have go-daddy hosting.

Comment: GD isn't exactly user friendly, but try `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` as the first line of index.php (since php 5.1.0+)

Answer (score 0):

edit your config.php file
from

```
    $config['time_reference'] = 'local';
```

to

```
    $config['time_reference'] = 'UTC';
```